# Node.js fs module and windows paths

Tags: node.js, windows, fs

Does the Node.js fs module implicitly convert Windows folder path separators from `'\\'` to `'/'`?

For example, if I use this call on Windows:

```
fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(function(file) {

});
```

file argument has `'/'` path separators, not `'\\'`, why is that?

Comment: Yes... Now the path separator is not an issue to tackle

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes it does.  See more: [Writing cross-platform Node.js](http://shapeshed.com/writing-cross-platform-node/)

Be sure to use [`path.join`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths) and [`path.normalize`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths) instead of having explicit path separators (`/`, `\`, `\\`, etc) in your code.

Comment: and use `path.sep` where necessary, instead of explicit path separators

Comment: For those who are curious, this is the source code of `path` in Node.js https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/path.js

Comment: With the caveats around `node:path/posix` and friend.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes. The documentation includes [this](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathwin32):

> path.win32
>
> The `path.win32` property provides access to Windows-specific implementations of the path methods.
>
> The API is accessible via `require('node:path').win32` or `require('node:path/win32')`.

The docs also include [this](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathposix):

> path.posix
>
> The `path.posix` property provides access to POSIX specific implementations of the path methods.
>
> The API is accessible via `require('node:path').posix` or `require('node:path/posix')`.

This only really becomes an issue for me when dealing with "drive letters": I try to keep everything relative, but there are times when that is not possible.